# Screens Design get mixed at angular navigation in windows phone html5 app

Tags: html, angularjs, css, windows-phone

Advance thanks for help,
 In All application two screens contents mixed with each other at navigation. In iphone and android it works fine but not in windows.  I am using angular js 1.2.3, cordova 2.9.1, ngular-animate.min.js
 please help.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about the problem you having. More details are needed, and show us the relevant parts of what you have already tried.

Comment: Can please see the below link for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730660/at-angular-navigation-designs-mixed-in-windows-phonegap-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **Remove css position "Absolute" or "Fixed"**. angular animation does't work with this css in windows phone or use jquery to set position fixed or absolute after page load