# At Angular Navigation .Designs mixed in windows phonegap app

Tags: html, angularjs, windows-phone-7, cordova

In All application two screens contents get mixed with each other at navigation.

In iphone and android it works fine but not in windows.

I am using angular js 1.2.3, cordova 2.9.1, angular-animate.min.js please help.

When i Click My club after that "home" screen contains and "my Club" screen contains get mixed with each other and then display "my Club" screen

[image: Home Screen]

[image: first navigation]

[image: My Club]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **Remove css position  "Absolute" or "Fixed".**
angular animation does't work with this css in windows phone or use jquery to set position fixed or absolute after page load